# EE Search Problem

Tags: search

I have never had this issue before but I am working on a site and implimented a simple search form like this:

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="about" result_page="site/search"}
<p>
<label for="keywords">Search:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
</p>                        
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

When I enter a search term and click submit I get a blank page that says:

"Safari can't open this page mytesturl.com%20/ because the page's address isn't valid"

And see that it is in fact trying to go to mytesturl.com%20/

This makes no sense - tried a few things but no luck yet.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Guy

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like you have a space after your 'URL to the root directory of your site' in 'Admin' > 'General Configuration' settings.